# Using the command nohup for matlab

Tags: matlab, nohup

I would like to launch a matlab script in the background on a remote server by using the command `nohup`. When I type the command line:

```
nohup matlab MyFile.m outfile.txt &
```

I can't find the .mat files and I don't know where to find them (The execution result of my script)? and the outfile.txt is very large and contains only the error messages...

Another question, how can I follow the progress of the execution of my script? Nothing appears on the command window of Matlab when I type the command line above...

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've found that using a `screen` or `tmux` session a better road than backgrounding a process if that's an option, especially with matlab. Not quite an answer but just a thought for you. Often I have to go back to that session and check a status or some feedback output.

Comment: In your script add `set -x` and every following command will be echoed to stdout. Use `set +x` later in your script to turn the feature off.